# Read from a file and compare the content with a variable

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, rpm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
some code........
..................
system ("rpm -q iptables > /tmp/checkIptables");
my $iptables = open FH, "/tmp/checkIptables";
```

The above code checks whether `iptables` is installed in your Linux machine? If it is installed the command `rpm -q iptables` will give the output as shown below:

```
iptables-1.4.7-3.el6.x86_64
```

Now I have redirected this output to the file named as `checkIptables`.

Now I want to check whether the variable `$iptables` matches with the output given above or not. I do not care about version numbers.

It should be something like

```
if ($iptables eq iptables*){
...............
.......................}
```

But iptables* gives error.

Comment: `open` just returns a value indicating whether the open operation was successful or not -- it doesn't return the contents of the thing being opened. That is, `$iptables` doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My method was wrong. I have got the right solution now which is working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex to check the string:

```
$iptables =~ /^iptables/
```

Also, you do not need a tmp file, you can instead open a pipe:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '-|', "rpm -q iptables";
my $line = <$fh>;
if ($line =~ /^iptables/) {
    print "iptables is installed";
}
```

This will read the first line of the output, and check it against the regex.

Or you can use backticks:

```
my $lines = `rpm -q iptables`;
if ($lines =~ /^iptables/) {
    print "iptables is installed";
}
```

Note that backticks may return more than one line of data, so you may need to compensate for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a regular expression or a "pattern match". You want the string to *match* a pattern, not a particular thing.

```
if ( $iptables =~ /^iptables\b/ ) { 
   ...
}
```

`=~` is the *binding* operator and tells the supplied regular expression that its source is that variable. The regular expression simply says look at the beginning of the string for the sequence "iptables" followed by a "word-break". Since '-' is a "non-word" character (not alphanumeric or '_') it breaks the word. You could use '-' as well:

```
/^iptables-/
```

But you can probably do the whole thing with this statement:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw<any>;

...
if ( any { m/^iptables-/ } `rpm -q iptables` ) {
    ...
}
```

piping the output directly into a list via backticks and searching through that list via `any` (See [`List::MoreUtils::any`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils#any_BLOCK_LIST)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look at the return value of "rpm -q", which will return 0 or 1 whether it is installed or not respectively?